# How to set a socket read timeout in IOManager

Tags: scala, akka

In Akka, IOManager "is the recommended entry point to creating sockets for performing IO."  I'm looking at the API and was wondering how to set a read timeout?  Of course, I can just schedule an actor to fire a message in n seconds to close the socket, but it may have already received all the read in that time and is now working on processing the read-in data.  So, it's not truly a read timeout.  Any ideas how to do this?  Or must I somehow introduce some state to my actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Derek Williams gave me a hint on akka-user.  Here's the code, just in case anyone else needs to do something similar.

When we accept a new client, we set a timer for 5 seconds to close the connection.

```
def receive = {
  case IO.NewClient(server) =>
    val socket = server.accept()
    val readTimeout = context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 seconds, self, Timeout(socket))
    state(socket) flatMap (_ => MyServer.processRequest(socket, readTimeout))

  case IO.Read(socket, bytes) =>
    state(socket)(IO Chunk bytes)

  case IO.Closed(socket, cause) =>
    state(socket)(IO EOF None)
    state -= socket

  case Timeout(socket) =>
    socket.close()
}
```

And to cancel the timeout after we've read, we call cancel() on the Cancellable schedule.

```
object MyServer {
  def processRequest(socket: IO.SocketHandle, readTimeout: Cancellable): IO.Iteratee[Unit] =
    for {
      request <- readRequest
    } yield {
      readTimeout.cancel()

      request match {
          val response = ...
          socket write ByteString(response).compact
          socket.close()
      }
    }
}
```